# Multi upload files to laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8. I want to upload multi files.

```
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'attaches' => 'required',
        'attaches.*' => 'mimes:csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf,jpg'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasfile('attaches')) {
        $images = $request->file('attaches'); 
        //dd($images); it shows below logs.
        foreach($images as $image) {
            dd("to upload"); //it doesn't show.
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $image->storeAs('uploads', $name, 'public');

            File::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'path' => '/storage/'.$path
            ]);
        }
    }
```

but my loop doesn't show anything!
my first `dd` function log:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1475
  -test: false
  -originalName: "21lu921.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\Users\S.M_Emamian\AppData\Local\Temp"
  filename: "phpAB07.tmp"
  basename: "phpAB07.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\Users\S.M_Emamian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAB07.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\Users\S.M_Emamian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAB07.tmp"
  aTime: 2021-05-28 11:12:05
  mTime: 2021-05-28 11:12:05
  cTime: 2021-05-28 11:12:05
  inode: 2814749767112182
  size: 1229865
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\Users\S.M_Emamian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAB07.tmp"
}
```

Comment: do you have input name="attaches[]" in your input type file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed array in input name like below

```
  <input type="file" name="attaches[]" multiple>
```